# How to set UISplitViewController delegate in IB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I've always set my delegate for my `UISplitViewController` in code, but I happen to be writing something where it would just be nicer if I could do it in the Interface Builder.

The `delegate` outlet exists for the `UISplitViewController`, but for the life of me, I can't figure a way to connect it anything in IB.

Am I missing something obvious or is impossible and Xcode is just messing with me by making it looking like it would work if I dragged to the correct object with my left eye closed under a full moon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time searching and finding no way to accomplish this... all signs point to this not being possible.